# Long Paths with Plastic SCM and node.js project

Tags: windows, node.js, unc, plasticscm

I am using Plastic SCM v4.x (on windows 7/8) and have a projects that uses node.js.  The modules and module dependencies in the project create path lengths that are > 259 characters.  Windows explorer has a problem with this when I try to access the files on a mapped drive.  I changes the path to a UNC and the windows explorer stopped having problems.  Git, node.js and RoboCopy have no problem accessing the files.

I created a repository with a local path as a UNC (e.g. \MyMachine\c$\source\project).  When I check for pending change, the files show up, when I attempt to check them in, the client complains that the file cannot be located.  *(ASSUMPTION: Plastic is resolving the UNC to a local path and trying to use the local path in the call to the API to get the files)*

I am hoping that someone has experienced this problem and has a work-around, fix or perhaps can tell me that upgrading to version 5 will work.

I am going to try making a windows share on my local machine and mapping the repository to the named share (assuming that the GUI is resolving the UNC to a local path) to force the GUI to use the UNC path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @BuckWheat, I see you mention your repo is at a UNC path but I assume you mean a workspace, correct? Repos in Plastic are always inside the database, not inside a user path. That being said, I also assume you know that using a network mounted workspace will be probably slower, but I guess you really need it to be in a shared location for a good reason. Question: what is the workspace path you see in the Plastic client? Are you seeing the UNC or the old mapped drive? Are you using the GUI or the ShellExtension?